# LVM setup advice

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, lvm

As I understand it, using LVM is the preferred method when setting up Ubuntu. After reading a little about LVM on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm I decided to reinstall Ubuntu with LVM in mind.

My desktop computer is using a 500GB SSD, 4TB, and a 2TB hard drives setup. I want to have Ubuntu utilize the 500GB and 4TB hard drives. I will eventually dual boot into Windows, so the 2TB hard drive is reserved for Windows.

As I understand it there are three concepts that LVM manages. **Physical Volumes** which are the actual hard drives I can physically install. **Logical Volumes** which are symbolic hard drives I may create by partitioning a physical hard drive into several sections. Finally, the **Volume Groups** which is a grouping of physical volumes and logical volumes.

This is why I think I can tell my Ubuntu OS that the computer has one volume group, managed by LVM, and that group will be made up of the 500GB SSD and 4TB HHD. I am hoping that when I look at my computer's properties it will display the sum of these drive's storage.

So, I first installed Ubuntu by erasing the disk and using LVM on the 500GB SSD. Then I used gparted to format the 4TB hard drive in LVM2 PV and I opened a terminal and used the following commands:

```
sudo lvm vgextend ubuntu-vg /dev/sdb1
```

This seemed to work. When I use the vgdisplay command it shows that the volume group is the sum of the two hard drives I combined. However, the properties of / reflects only the 500GB. Is this one of the perks to using LVM? Did I do this right?

Comment: IMHO, combining an SSD and a HDD is not a good idea, for many reasons - one of which is the fact of TBW counting against the lifespan of the SSD.

Comment: Trying to navigate through Linux is so disorienting. I just don't have a good enough grasp on every new topic I stumble upon everyday. It never occurred to me that combining the SSD and HDD as one Volume Group would be foolish because when the SSD met its end, I would lose all of my data. I guess what I would like to do is similar to what I had before I started experimenting with LVM. Make the SSD contain the EFI and root partitions. Then make the HDD contain the swap and /home partitions. This way if the computer fails, I can hang onto my home directory files. How do I do this with LVM flare

Comment: I personally haven't ever used LVM. As a matter of fact, I've never even installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode. I absolutely **DESPISE** UEFI. I also have never installed Ubuntu to a GUID partition. I'll stick with my Legacy Boot and MBR partition tables :)

I say all that to say, I don't really know how you would do it. However, I'm sure there are other users here who do. I'll post this question in the chatroom.

Comment: Well, with UEFI I can make sure that nothing unapproved is booted on my laptop. Only grub executable that is signed by me can be booted. And then everything else is encrypted. So a bit of protection from evil-maid attack...

Comment: @AndroidDev It's worth noting that LVM has _nothing_ to do with UEFI, it's more analogous to Microsoft's Dynamic Disks feature. I've never worked on a UEFI machine, but I'm very much an LVM convert. The convenience and power of being able to grow, shrink, and move filesystems as needed, within or between physical disk partitions, all _on the fly_ without even unmounting them (even while they're actively in use by the system), can't really be conveyed — it just has to be experienced to be appreciated. You'll never go back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only extended the size of the Volume Group but didn't extend the size of your logical volume and the size of the file system.

E.g. to increase logical volume you need

`lvresize --size +4T /dev/ubuntu-vg/substitute_your_rootfs_volume_name`

4TB might be a bit too much depending on your LVM PV size (then reduce it a bit). That's why it is a bit easier to use GUIs...

To resize your file system, you first need to check what filesystem you are using. E.g. for ext4 you can use

`sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/substitute_your_rootfs_volume_name`

or for btrfs

`sudo btrfs filesystem resize max /`

(You can grow ext4 and btrfs online, you don't need to unmount them)

P.S. if you want to work from GUI, you can try KDE Partition Manager 3.0 (Available on Ubuntu 17.04), it supports much more LVM operations compared to GParted, e.g. you will be able to extend/reduce volume groups, resize logical volumes, etc.

Also it won't necesseraly be the case that SSD will stop working before HDD. Modern SSDs work fairly well. As long as you have backups, I wouldn't be scared combining them into single VG. Of course then the location of LVM LVs would determine which ones are fast (on SSD) and which ones are slow.

Comment: The KDE Partition Manager 3.0 is exactly what I need. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the terminal. The resize2fs is also what I needed. Admittedly, I have up on LVM for now because I tried several other things, but I am sure resize2fs would have fixed my issue or the KDE Partition Manager. Thanks.

Comment: You can actually have `lvresize` automatically resize the underlying filesystem for you, along with the containing LV. Just pass it the `-r` flag.

Comment: @FeRD depends on file system. lvresize -r is a bit limited. Yeah, probably that's easier option for ext4 file systems but I don't think it can do btrfs. Never mind something more complicated like luks encrypted stuff...

Comment: @AndriusŠtikonas True enough, it's documented as using `fsadm` under the hood, which according to its own manpage "tries to use the same API for ext2, ext3, ext4, ReiserFS and XFS filesystem". So, if the filesystem is one of those, `lvresize -r` should be the simplest route.