# how to install ubuntu on all my disks

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a Toshiba wish I replaced the windows 7 hdd with an ssd; I also  replaced my dvd drive with another ssd. I managed to use ubuntu 16.xx two years ago, and always managed to upgrade....but I suspect that my second ssd (the dvd drive) still remains 16.04.

Now that I have downloaded 18.04, how can I fresh install it on all the disks?

Thanks in advance to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine the two hard drives into one single volume it is LVM (Logical Volume Management) you are looking for.

Check out this post: [LVM setup advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870422/lvm-setup-advice)

Lets say you have 2 SSD drives with 250GB each. You can then create one volume that is 500GB large and partition it as you wish.

You can also read more about LVM here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I must try it. Best regards