# Ubuntu Server shows smaller disk size than it actually is

Tags: partitioning, disk

I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS installed in a 1TB HDD. I installed it with the default disk partitioning options.

When I logged in for the first time, the welcome message showed this

```
Usage of /: 3.2% of 195.86GB
```

Which is lower than ~1TB. Then I ran df -h

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              408M  2.9M  405M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  211G  6.7G  193G   4% /
tmpfs                              2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          1.1G  110M  844M  12% /boot
/dev/loop1                          59M   59M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop0                          74M   74M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19647
/dev/loop2                          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/10707
/dev/loop5                          34M   34M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11402
/dev/loop3                          59M   59M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop4                          74M   74M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19188
tmpfs                              408M     0  408M   0% /run/user/1000
```

This is the output of fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000DM003-1CH1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D5D5EBEA-1595-4DC3-80A0-42FAB799782F

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048       4095       2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096    2101247    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2101248 1953521663 1951420416 930.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

I don't understand what's going on here. What is that 200GB /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv "disk"?

Comment: Looks like the system has been installed with a 200GB LVM volume.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LVM setup advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870422/lvm-setup-advice)